# Deleted nodes appears in Views VBO list with their pathauto links

Tags: 6, nodes, views

Deleted nodes appears in Views VBO lists with their pathauto links.

I have custom VBO view which I use to delete filtered nodes. After processing I get this message i.e. 'Skipped Delete node on node id 251'. It's probably because the node doesn't exist, but in the views list it's still listed and has its original title and path to it and when clicked it gives page not found.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try to flush the cache before running the VBO. :)

Comment: Don't help, tried that.

Comment: Can you try to make a screenshot of this VBO view :) 
What are your filters

Comment: Can you also confirm that node 251 is deleted :) and not unpublished, for example

Comment: Screenshot added. As you see it's published and when clicking edit it gives Page not found. Also all those nodes has same date and time.

Comment: Well described. :) 
What happens if you type in a url www.yoursite.com/node/251 ..

Still no page ?

I am just thinking if it alias problem :) 
In the view->can you add filter -> content->published

Comment: I tried that before, didn't help. Both options.

Comment: "it's published and when clicking edit it gives Page not found" - OK, and how does it look like directly in DB?

Comment: I added a DB screenshot at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted directly from database.